# Where are these buildings?

Tags: identify-this, architecture

I would like to know where this is from.

[image]

Comment: What does the source of the stock image say?

Comment: @DavidRicherby nothing useful

Answer (score 4):

The [image's page on the stock photo website](https://www.dreamstime.com/blank-billboard-twilight-next-to-skyscrapers-d-rendering-blank-billboard-night-time-city-next-to-skyscrapers-road-image121603373) doesn't provide any useful information about the location ("Blank billboard at night time in the city next to skyscrapers and road with lights on the frame. 3d rendering"), but the towers looked familiar.

That photo was taken in the [Moscow International Business Centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_International_Business_Center). [This stock photo](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-scenic-view-with-skyscrapers-of-the-moscow-city-international-business-136000395.html) shows a wider angle of the area. You can recognise a few buildings, but especially the [City of Capitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Capitals): the two large towers to the left of centre, with the distinctive rotation between sections.

More specifically, the image was taken from approximately [this location](https://goo.gl/maps/e52P9MwidFo1QNcW7) and has been mirrored horizontally. The "3D rendering" part of the image description presumably relates to the blank billboard.